# How does Apache Spark assign partition-ids to its executors

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a long-running Spark streaming job which uses 16 executors which only one core each.

I use default partitioner(`HashPartitioner`)  to equally distribute data to 16 partitions. Inside `updateStateByKey`function, i checked for the partition id from `TaskContext.getPartitionId()` for multiple batches and found out the partition-id of a executor is quite consistent but still changing to another id after a long run.

I'm planing to do some optimization to spark "updateStateByKey" API, but it can't be achieved if the partition-id keeps changing among batches.

So when does Spark change the partition-id of a executor?

Comment: `getPartitionId` isn't an id of the executor. It's the ID of the partition in the given RDD.

Comment: Partition id i was talking about is id of partition which is handled by a specific executor, and i wonder when the executor change the id of partition it has been handling.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the task has failed and restart again, so the TaskContext has changed, and so as the partitionId.